# agregar video a un slider de imagenes

Tags: javascript, video, slider

como dice el titulo tengo un código de un slider  que me gusta mucho pero megustaria poder colocar videos las imágenes y caption las pongo desde javascript  y en html solo tengo contenedores vacíos a ver si podéis echarme una mano mi código js es el siguiente:

`$(function() {

```
var sliderImages = [
    "https://picsum.photos/1920/1080",
    "https://picsum.photos/1920/1081",  
];
var sliderNames = [
    "uno",
    "dos",
]
var sliderCaption = [
    "uno",
    "uno mas",
]
var slideID = 0;
var sliderLength = sliderImages.length;

var $slider = $(".slider");
var $sliderImage = $(".slider__image");
var $sliderNav = $(".slider__nav ul");
var $sliderTitle = $(".slider__title");
var $sliderCaption = $(".slider__caption");

// Populate slider nav with slide names
sliderNames.forEach(function(name, id) {
    $sliderNav.append("<li data-slide-id='" + id + "'></li>");
});

var $sliderNames = $(".slider__nav ul li");
var intervalID;
var nextAction;

// Manual navigation
$sliderNames.on("click", function() {
    $sliderNames.removeClass("active");
    slide(parseInt($(this).attr("data-slide-id")));
})

slide(0);

function slide(id) {
    // Unload slide
    setLoader()`
```

mas js
`if (id === undefined) {
slideID++
if (slideID >= sliderLength) {
slideID = 0;
}
} else {
slideID = id;
}
window.clearTimeout(nextAction);
nextAction = window.setTimeout(function() {
displayImage(slideID);
}, 1000);
}

```
function setLoader(i) {
    $sliderNames.removeClass("active");
    $slider.addClass("loading");
    $sliderTitle.removeClass("animated");
    $sliderCaption.removeClass("animated");
}

function displayImage(id, callback) {
    $slider.removeClass("loading");
    $sliderImage.css('background-image', "url(" + sliderImages[id] + ")");
    $sliderImage.toggleClass("zoomed");
    $($sliderNames[id]).addClass("active");
    $($sliderCaption[id]).addClass("active");

    $sliderTitle.text(sliderNames[id]);
    $sliderTitle.addClass("animated");
    
    $sliderCaption.text(sliderCaption[id]);
    $sliderCaption.addClass("animated");

    window.clearTimeout(nextAction);
    nextAction = window.setTimeout(slide, 50000);
}
```

});`

aqui esta el html

```
<section class="slider">
<div class="slider__image"></div>
<div class="slider__image">
    </div>


<main class="slider__main">
    <div class="slider__content">
        <div class="slider__title-container">
            <div class="slider__title"></div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="slider__caption-container">
            <div class="slider__caption"></div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <aside class="slider__right">
        <div class="slider__nav">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </aside>
</main>
```

Comment: Puedes agregar también tu código `html` aunque sean contenedores vacíos. Cuantos mas detalles no compartas, más fácil será ayudarte.

Comment: gracias por responder   esque no me dejaba pegar mas codigo  de hecho el js esta cortado lo modifico a ver si me deja